# ¿Cómo agrupar 6 divs?

Tags: css, html5

Quiero saber cómo poner 6 `div` en el `div` negro. Si no me equivoco se usa un atributo flex, pero no sé cual.

[image: Algo asi quiero hacer...]

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container-right {
  width: 40rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.h2-container-right {
  margin-top: 6rem;
}

.separator-icon-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  max-width: 12rem;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.icon-right {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  color: yellowgreen;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.separator-container-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon-container-right {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.grupo {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0.7rem 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body class="body">

  <div class="container-right ">
    <h2 class="h2-container-right">Grupos</h2>

    <div class="separator-container-right">
      <div class="separator-icon-right"></div>
      <i class="fas fa-star icon-right"></i>
      <div class="separator-icon-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grupo">
      <div class="1"></div>
      <div class="2"></div>
      <div class="3"></div>
      <div class="4"></div>
      <div class="5"></div>
      <div class="6"></div>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Te sugiero leas [aqui sobre flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) te ayudará a aprenderlo y con ello tu mismo serás capaz de darle respuesta a tu duda

Comment: Ok mi estimado amigo, lo leere si no consigo una respuesta te digo a ver si tu me puedes ayudar

Comment: Oye bro quiero decir que muchas gracias, me funciono correctamente !!!!

Comment: Para no dejar la pregunta abandonada pues responderla tu mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo usaría `Flexbox` para poder hacerlo mas rápido te muestro el código que implemente y te explico dentro de el para que sirven, por otro lado si te interesa aprender mas sobre `Flexbox` te dejo este [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
            .body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.container-right {
  width: 40rem;
  height: 100rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.h2-container-right {
  margin-top: 6rem;
}

.separator-icon-right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.2rem;
  max-width: 12rem;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  background-color: black;
}

.icon-right {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  color: yellowgreen;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.separator-container-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon-container-right {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.grupo {
  height: 20rem;
  width: 94%;
  margin: 0.7rem 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  display: flex; /*Convertimos al contenedor en flexbox*/
  justify-content: space-between; /*Con esto le indicamos que margine todos los items que se encuentra adentro hacia la derecha e izquierda*/
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*Con esto le indicamos que si llega al margen del contenedor que se posicione abajo del otro item*/
  padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.item {
    background: #22B14C;
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-right ">
          <h2 class="h2-container-right">Grupos</h2>
      
          <div class="separator-container-right">
            <div class="separator-icon-right"></div>
            <i class="fas fa-star icon-right"></i>
            <div class="separator-icon-right"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="grupo">
            <div class="item">1</div>
            <div class="item">2</div>
            <div class="item">3</div>
            <div class="item">4</div>
            <div class="item">5</div>
            <div class="item">6</div>
          </div>
      
      
        </div>
```

Espero ayudarte con esto, cualquier cosa me comentas, Suerte!

Comment: Oye amigo gracias, esta me funciona perfecto!!